# gnome-shell crash

Tags: fedora, gnome

I installed Fedora like 4 days and it start crash with that reason: 'gnome-shell killed by SIGABRT'

Logs:

```
User Logs:
--Aug 09 21:55:49 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: gvc_mixer_ui_device_get_id: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_UI_DEVICE (device)' failed
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: No such device
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau: ch5: krec 0 pushes 1 bufs 12 relocs 0
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau: ch5: buf 00000000 00000013 00000004 00000004 00000000 0x7fc31ff80000 0x1d20000 0x80000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau: ch5: buf 00000001 00000006 00000004 00000000 00000004 0x7fc347ea0000 0x224000 0x1000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau: ch5: buf 00000002 00000236 00000002 00000000 00000002 (nil) 0x3735000 0x1000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau: ch5: buf 00000003 0000004d 00000004 00000004 00000000 0x7fc340c07000 0x376f000 0x1000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau: ch5: buf 00000004 000001dc 00000002 00000000 00000002 (nil) 0x370f000 0x1000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau: ch5: buf 00000005 0000011d 00000004 00000004 00000000 0x7fc340c06000 0x3773000 0x1000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau: ch5: buf 00000006 0000002b 00000002 00000002 00000002 (nil) 0x38e0000 0x80000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau: ch5: buf 00000007 0000018f 00000002 00000002 00000000 (nil) 0x68a0000 0x20000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau: ch5: buf 00000008 00000008 00000002 00000002 00000000 (nil) 0x360000 0xe0000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau: ch5: buf 00000009 0000000b 00000002 00000002 00000000 (nil) 0x1980000 0x20000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau: ch5: buf 0000000a 0000000a 00000002 00000002 00000002 (nil) 0x1880000 0x100000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau: ch5: buf 0000000b 0000002f 00000002 00000000 00000002 (nil) 0x3960000 0x80000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau: ch5: psh 00000000 000004fa00 000004fb70
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x200181c2
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x03303210
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x200681c3
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00001020
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000018
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000018
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000001
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x20088100
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x0376f000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x03735000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000060
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000080
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000018
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000018
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x200180c0
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000686
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x200181c2
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x03303210
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x200681c3
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00001020
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000018
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000018
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000001
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x20088100
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x03773000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x0370f000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000060
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000080
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000018
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000018
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x200180c0
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000686
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x200203fd
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x07830000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00230000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x20090200
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x038e0000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000783
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000023
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x000000d5
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000030
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000001
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x200503f8
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x03960000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000016
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000030
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x2001054e
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000001
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x2003048a
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000783
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000023
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00010001
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x200105e7
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x20010487
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x0fac6881
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x80000574
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x80000044
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x800101d5
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x200308e0
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00010000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00400000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0xa00308e3
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x000001a0
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x3f000000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x3f000000
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x20040360
Aug 09 21:56:01 fedora gnome-shell[1851]: nouveau:         0x00000000
--
```

I tried disable all gnome extensions but it don't give effect

Comment: If you blacklist `nouveau`, do the crashes stop?